# Can't compress a recycled bitmap when saving it on Parse

Tags: android, bitmap, parse-platform

I'm developing an application where I want to take a picture from the smartphone's gallery and then crop it, next I would like to save it on Parse.com

But i'm facing a problem trying to save the picture on parse, having an error " Can't compress a recycled bitmap"

here is my code to retrieve image from gallery and then upload it to ImageView :

```
Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.blink);
profil.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
Intent intent = new Intent();
 // call android default gallery
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 // ******** code for crop image
 intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
 intent.putExtra("aspectX", 200);
 intent.putExtra("aspectY", 200);
 intent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
 intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
 intent.putExtra("scale", true);
 intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
 intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

 try {
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
    "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
 } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
     // Do nothing for now
 }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
            TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[]{
            new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent),
            new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), getCircleBitmap(photo))
            });
            profil.setImageDrawable(td);
            td.startTransition(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

and then i'm trying to save the bitmap file " Photo " and I'm not able to do that

here is the code of saving Photo bitmap into parse.com

```
final Bitmap bitmap = photo;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);  
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
file = new ParseFile("profil.png", image);
file.saveInBackground();

object.put("name", nom.getText().toString());                       
object.put("Profil",file);                     
object.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: `bitmap = photo` looks like the issue that's why its unable to compress. are you sure photo is valid object? You can use BitmapFactory() methods to get image reference, even directly via path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue, however to successful save a file in parse you need to wait for the file to save before trying to then store the file in a parse object i.e

```
final Bitmap bitmap = photo;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);  
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
file = new ParseFile("profil.png", image);

file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {  
    public void done(ParseException e) {   
        if(null == e){
            object.put("name", nom.getText().toString());                       
            object.put("Profil",file);                     
            object.saveInBackground();        
        }
    }
});
```